How can I manage assigned tasks in Word
Word has feature that allows you to assign tasks to yourself or colleagues using comments and @ tags.
Is there a way to find an overiew of all tasks in a document assigned to someone? Otherwise it's easy to miss assignments between all the regular comments.
I know I can search for the name of an assignee in the navigation pane and it will highlight all sections with a comment assigned to them, but it's rather crude and does not distinguis between regular tags and assignments.

Additionally, it appears that with the in-browser version of Word, the "find" function does not search in comments.
